# Cannot get background.js to work with new manifest v3 notation

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, chrome-extension-manifest-v3

I wrote some extensions a while ago with manifest v2 and now wanted to write a new one but somehow I cannot get the background.js to run. Meaning that the script does seemingly not execute at all.

**manifest.json**

```
{
    "manifest_version": 3,
    "name": "extension",
    "description": "example",
    "version": "1.0",
    "permissions": [
        "scripting",
        "tabs"
    ],
    "host_permissions": ["https://*.example.com/*"],
    "background": {
        "service_worker": "background.js"
    },
    "action": {
        "default_title": "Click Me",
        "default_popup": "popup.html"
    }
}
```

**content_script.js**

```
chrome.runtime.sendMessage({
  url: window.location.href,
})
```

**background.js**

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function (request, sender, sendResponse) {
  console.log("Foo")
})
```

**I'm also getting this console output:**

> Manifest: property 'url' ignored, should be within scope of the
> manifest.
>
> Manifest: property 'url' of 'shortcut' not present.

Comment: Service workers can't use `alert`. Use console.log instead.

Comment: Does not work either.

Comment: [How to see background.js console?](/a/10258029)